# multi module npm build with common dependency in parent package.json

Tags: reactjs, npm

I have a project with reactjs which has parent folder and subfolder. Parent folder and each sub folder contains package.json.

When doing npm install on parent I am building subfolders also. But the problem is npm istall is taking more time because, in subfolder package.json has duplicate entry as parent package.json.

```
ParentFolder
     --SubFolder1
          package.json
      --SubFolder2
          package.json
    package.json
```

Parent package.json

```
{
  "name": "parent",
  "dependencies": {
    "react": "^16.8.6",
    "react-dom": "^16.8.6",
    "react-scripts": "3.0.0"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "subfolder1-build": "cd  SubFolder1 && npm install && npm run-script build",
    "subfolder2-build": "cd SubFolder1  && npm install && npm run-script build"
  }
}
```

Subfolder1 package.json

```
{
  "name": "Subfolder1",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "react": "^16.8.6",
    "react-dom": "^16.8.6",
    "react-scripts": "3.0.0"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": "react-app"
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  }
}
```

In subfolder1 package.json i have duplicate dependencies as parent package.jso

```
"react": "^16.8.6",
"react-dom": "^16.8.6",
"react-scripts": "3.0.0"
```

I am newbie to npm. Is it possible to add the common dependency in parent package.json and add only required dependency in subfolder package.json and how to refer the parent npm module in subfolder package.json?

Comment: Why do you need different package.json for different folders. Are those sub folders entirely different projects?

Comment: Actually I have dashboard with layout,KPI and gadgets so I want to separate it as modules.